# PHP How to sort associative array first by keys then by values?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, key

```
$arr =array(
    28 => 23,
    26 => 23,
    15 => 12,
    29 => 12,
    1 => 12,
    16 => 15,
    30 => 15,
    11 => 12,
    8 => 23,
    33 => 23
);
```

how to sort like this :

```
8 => 23
26 => 23
28 => 23
33 => 23
16 => 15
30 => 15
1 => 12
11 => 12
15 => 12
29 => 12
```

Comment: Your array is simply sorted by value, yes?

Comment: You have to write your function and use it as uksort() callback

Comment: I've merged your two accounts together.  [Please read this Faq entry about cookie-based accounts.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account/44562#44562)  Also, StackOverflow isn't a forum; if you have a new question, please ask a new question.  If you want to include more information in your question, please [edit it](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5377853/edit).  If you want to interact with one of the people who has answered, you can leave them a comment.

Answer (score 5):

Use [uksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php), but make the array available to the comparison function for the secondary comparison by value. Making it a global variable would be the quickest + dirtiest way.

Comment: Nice solution. Using a closure and passing a copy of the array in with use would be nice... Note you would actually have to pass the array to a different variable before passing it to the closure.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `uksort()` which enables the custom callback to take a look at both the keys and, indirectly, their associated values. Then it's a simple matter of deciding which comparisons to make and returning the appropriate greater-than-less-then-or-zero value to influence the sort order.

Here's an example using a closure around a temporary variable (see [Jacob's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377853/php-how-to-sort-associative-array-first-by-keys-then-by-values/5377939#5377939)) which should hopefully make sense.

```
$temp = $arr;
uksort($arr, function ($a,$b) use ($temp) {
    // Same values, sort by key ascending
    if ($temp[$a] === $temp[$b]) {
        return $a - $b;
    }
    // Different values, sort by value descending
    return $temp[$b] - $temp[$a];
});
unset($temp);
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy. First use [ksort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) and then use [asort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) for the new sorted array. You will find your result.

Comment: PHP's array sorting functions use quicksort which is unstable. So this can't be guaranteed.

Comment: @Jacob. Sorry dude I didnt understand your point. please explain me and correct me...

Comment: see [Stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Classification). In quicksort if two elements are equal they won't be guaranteed to maintain their original order.

Comment: @Jacob, I believe it's OK in this case, as there will be no equal items - each array element has unique key, which is taken into consideration in mike's case.